# Google Api PHP unable to pass variable to call('list')

Tags: php, google-api

I am trying to run the following code with the new Google Business Profile API:

```
$mybusinessbusinessinformationService = new Google\Service\MyBusinessBusinessInformation($client);
    try
       {
         $locations = $mybusinessbusinessinformationService->accounts_locations->call('list',['parent'=>'accounts/1111111111111111111']);
         var_dump($locations);
       } catch(Exception $e){
         var_dump(print_r($e->getMessage(),1));
       }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
(list) missing required param: 'parent'
```

As far as I can tell it seems that I am parsing the param properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people that are searching for an answer:
Since Google updated its API, it's a requirement to parse readMask as well:

```
 $mybusinessbusinessinformationService = new Google\Service\MyBusinessBusinessInformation($client);
$params = array('readMask'=> "title,name");               
$locations = $mybusinessbusinessinformationService->accounts_locations->listAccountsLocations($getAccountName,$params);

var_dump($locations);
```

You can find the mask parameters here:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations